# Easy way to serialize/deserialize public enums?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, enums

I am having some trouble trying to serialize/deserialize some `enum` in Java. Here is my enum class:

FrequencyType.java:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public enum FrequencyType {
    NONE,
    HOURLY,
    DAILY,
    WEEKLY,
    MONTHLY;
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object createFrequency(@RequestBody FrequencyType frequencyType) throws Exception {
    ...
    frequencyManager.createFrequency(frequencyType);
    ...
}
```

I am trying to use the `createFrequency` method to take in a `FrequencyType` as `json` input. Here is an example of my input:

```
{
    "frequencyType": "HOURLY"
}
```

However, whenever I try to invoke this method via my REST API, I get an error saying:

> "Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.zuora.cds.api.schedule.FrequencyType out of START_OBJECT token\n
>   at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@225337f8; line: 1, column: 1];
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.zuora.cds.api.schedule.FrequencyType out
>   of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@225337f8; line: 1, column: 1]",

I have tried to add in the above `JsonInclude` and `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotationis but that doesn't seem to help. I also tried to add `getters` and `setters` like so:

```
FrequencyType getNone() {
    return FrequencyType.NONE;
}
FrequencyType getHourly() {
    return FrequencyType.HOURLY;
}
FrequencyType getDaily() {
    return FrequencyType.DAILY;
}
FrequencyType getWeekly() {
    return FrequencyType.WEEKLY;
}
FrequencyType getMonthly() {
    return FrequencyType.MONTHLY;
}
void setNone(FrequencyType frequencyType) {
    this.equals(frequencyType);
}
void setHourly(FrequencyType frequencyType) {
    this.equals(frequencyType);
}
void setDaily(FrequencyType frequencyType) {
    this.equals(frequencyType);
}
void setWeekly(FrequencyType frequencyType) {
    this.equals(frequencyType);
}
void setMonthly(FrequencyType frequencyType) {
    this.equals(frequencyType);
}
```

so that the POJO representation would hopefully transform the JSON into a `FrequencyType` but I end up getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try `{"frequencyType": 1}`, if that doesn't work `Serialize` a `FrequencyType` and see what your library expects.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you elaborate what you mean to work `Serialize` a `FrequencyType`? The first method didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum types in Jackson are typically serialized and deserialized raw, as JSON **strings**.

You're trying to deserialize a JSON **object** as an enum

```
{
    "frequencyType": "HOURLY"
}
```

That's a JSON object with a single name-value pair with name `frequencyType` and a value that is a JSON string.

You'll need to create a POJO to wrap this object

```
class FrequencyTypeWrapper {
    private FrequencyType frequencyType;

    // getters and setters
}
```

[Jackson will eventually support a `@JsonWrapped` annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/42) which you'll likely be able to add to your enum type, indicating that you want it to be wrapped with some name in a root object.

The alternative is to write and register your own `JsonDeserializer` for that enum type that does the appropriate conversion, ie. parses a JSON object, extracts a name-value pair, and converts the String value to an enum value.

---

If you're not deserializing anything else to JSON in your code, you can configure your `ObjectMapper` to unwrap the root value.

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

You'd have to configure the root name for your `enum` type as well

```
@JsonRootName("frequencyType")
enum FrequencyType {
    HOURLY /* more */;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. So then I would make some class something like this: `public class FrequencyTypeWrapper {
    private FrequencyType frequencyType;

 public FrequencyType getFrequencyType() {
  return frequencyType;
 }
 public void setFrequencyType(String frequencyType) {
                String result = frequencyType;
                //Parse frequencyType...
  this.frequencyType = result;
 }
}`

Comment: @user1871869 Yes, and you would use that type for the parameter of your handler method. There are other options (but they might not be useful in all cases), see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

Add the following annotations:

-1.

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
    public enum FrequencyType {
```

-2. add the following annotation to to the setter:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = EnumDeserializer.class)
```